# Is this a correct loop back to my original prompt function? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, prompt

I have a really simple Javascript function that's based off of a variable taken from a prompt. If the input in the prompt is neither a number nor a string, I want it to automatically loop back to the prompt so the user can write the input again. Is this code correct for that?

```
var a = prompt("please enter a number");
function tys() {
    if (typeof a == 'string') {
        document.write("You exited.");
    } else if (isNaN(a)) {
        document.write(a-10);
    } else {
        document.write("Input invalid. Please write another input.");
        tys();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do that while a is false... and you'll also need to invoke tys after it's defined... () ... so .. do tys(); while (!a);

Comment: This is how you loop in functional programming; you've used a tail-recursive call there, which is important. What that means is the call, `tys();` is not a subexpression. It's appropriate to loop like this in JS, in fact it kinda gets a bit functional when you condense the logic like `let tys = a => typeof a === 'string' ? document.write('you exited') : isNaN(a) ? document.write(a-10) : document.write('input invalid, please write another') || tys();`... I should add that if you like this style of programming, try Haskell, F#, Rust, Scheme, etc...

Comment: Hmmm, having realise I contradicted myself, in my example `tys()` is a subexpression... but it is evaluated on its own and as the last part of the expression, which means there's nothing left to evaluate *after* the call... This is because I've used a tonne of *lazy operators* like `? ... :` and `||` in this code which act similar to `;` in that they act as barriers of evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

`do tys(); while(!a);` will call the function tys at least  one time but repeatedly if a is false.

That should do what you need, you may want to check a for a valid value in which case you would modify a to true only after parsing.

Keep in mind a will be the value input by the user or undefined if nothing was input or cancel was selected.

Answer (score 0):

The type of code you are looking for is called a while loop because it will continue to execute the code while the statement is true.

In your case, you want to keep going back to the user input if something is not met.

```
let canContinue = false;

while (canContinue === false) {
    const input = prompt("please enter input: ");
    if (input === "hello") canContinue = false;
}

// I will be hit once the user inputs hello"
```

In the above case we can see that we will continue to ask for input if the user does not input a value that matches "hello", but if they do then it will continue outside the while loop.

**Your current solution**

What you have currently done is called recursion, this is where you would keep calling the current function within its self. It can be used to create complex solutions but is not the best solution for what you are trying to learn (starting with the basics).

Hope this helps.